# After the events of Golden Wind, did Polnareff's soul stay in Coco Jumbo's body?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

In *JoJo's Bizarre Adventure: Golden Wind* (Part 5), did Polnareff's soul stay in Coco Jumbo's body after the events of Golden Wind?

Answer (score 0):

**We don't know.** He was never mentioned again in any media (at least in the 'main' universe, and not in the SBR universe, as I have not read part 7-8.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably.
We don't really hear about Polnareff after then, and we don't see Polnareff back in his body (except for flashbacks to part 3).